# The length of a line computed by Turf doesn't equal the sum of its segments

Tags: javascript, turfjs

I've stumbled into the following issue while using Turf to find coordinates along a line.

The sum of the distance from the start of the line to a point along that line and from that point to the end of the line doesn't equal to the length of that line.

Here is snippet showing the issue on a simple line.

```js
var line = turf.lineString([[-83, 30], [-84, 36], [-78, 41]]);
var point = turf.along(line, 200);
var start = turf.point(line.geometry.coordinates[0]);
var end = turf.point(line.geometry.coordinates[line.geometry.coordinates.length - 1]);

var startToPoint = turf.distance(start, point);
var pointToEnd = turf.distance(point, end);
var lineLength = turf.length(line);

console.log(startToPoint + pointToEnd, lineLength)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a reason why that is?